# Dashboard : remove Safari navigator message

Tags: wp-admin, admin, metabox, dashboard

Everytime when i login to wordpress backoffice with safari (only with safari navigator). I got the message on the picture below :

[image]

I want to **Delete definitely** this kind of message from the dashboard without update my navigator.

How can i do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why so much effort to remove that notice? There is a reason it's displayed for you. Updating Safari, Firefox or Chrome is soo painless and easy so I would  recommend you to use up-to-date browsers( in general ). Sorry for not giving you the answer you wanted to hear but it's well intentioned on my side.

Comment: it's for a client. do not want him to see this box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to that page:
http://wpcodesnippet.com/hide-browser-upgrade-warning-wordpress/

You can put this code into your functions.php to get rid of that notices:

```
// hide browser upgrade warning in wordpress
function wcs_disable_browser_upgrade_warning() {
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_browser_nag', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
}
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'wcs_disable_browser_upgrade_warning' );
```

I would tell your client the risks that might be comming with this - just to make sure that you won't be responsible if anything happens.

Hope the code works - I couldn't test for my browsers are updated ;)

Comment: Nice to hear it works!